# Is float always rounding?

Tags: c

Here is my program, it turn decimal to base-"n", you can put number in "n" base what you want to turn to, it run successful but I have a question, I don't get it why the `if ((float)input / (float)n <= 0)` can pass in the fifth time. I'm debugging with vscode and watch the value every breakpoints and steps, here are the result

(run this line `if ((float)input / (float)n <= 0)`)

input=20, n=2

First time : 20/2=10 (pass)

Second time : 10/2=5 (pass)

Third time : 5/2=2.5 (pass)

Forth time : 2.5/2=1 (pass) **I don't understand why it is "1" not "1.25" (I think this is my main problem, is float always rouding ?)**

Fifth time : 1/2=0.5 (pass)

Sixth time : 0.5/2=0 (fail and break)

Hope somebody can explain that I'll very appreciate, English not my mother tongue so forgive me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void rev(int num[]);

int cnt = 0;

int main()
{

int input = 20, num[10], i, n = 2;

// Decimal turn to base-n

printf("Decimal \"%d\" to base-%d = ", input, n);

for (i = 0; i < 10;)
{
    if ((float)input / (float)n <= 0)
        break;
    else
    {
        num[i] = input % n;
        input /= n;
        i++;
        cnt++;
    }
}
rev(num);

printf("\n");

system("pause");
return 0;
}

void rev(int num[])
{
int i;

i = cnt - 1;

for (i; i >= 0; i--)
    printf("%d", num[i]);
}
```

Comment: Note that `(float)input / (float)n` uses floating-point division (e.g. `5.0 / 2.0 == 2.5`), but `input /= n` uses integer division (e.g. `5 / 2 == 2`).

Comment: _Is `float` always rounding?_ Yes, a `float` is 4 bytes, a finite amount of storage, so you can only represent a finite amount of data. This is true no matter how large your data field is. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @0x5453 I understand what you say, integer division won't save the float. Thank you so much I think my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

absolutely will be fail because . when you type casting float to int like int a = 3.14 ; just the decimal part will be stored exp int a = 0.5; means a equal to 0 .

Comment: Thank you for the explained, I found my problem and I solved.

Answer (score 0):

When you divide `input` by `n`, you're doing *integer* division:

```
input /= n;
```

Integer division has an integer result.  And either way, you're storing the result back to an integer, so any fractional portion is discarded.

So the values stored in `input` each time through the loop will be `20`, `10`, `5`, `2` (*not* `2.5`), `1`, and `0`.

Comment: Thank you for the explained, I found my problem and I solved.